# How to set the tracking_specs when creating Facebook ads?

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to create an ad using the Facebook Marketing API. In order to create an ad inside a conversion based campaign, I am required to set proper `tracking_specs` values.

Querying existing ads (on other similar campaigns) I see the tracking spec is generally defined as follows:

```
"tracking_specs": [
    {
        "action.type": ["offsite_conversion"],
        "fb_pixel": [<pixel ID>]
    },
    {
        "action.type": ["post_engagement"],
        "page": [<page ID>],
        "post": [<post ID>]
    },
    {
        "action.type": ["link_click"],
        "post": [<post ID>],
        "post.wall": [<post.wall ID>]
    } 
]
```

How do I find the required `tracking_specs` values? More specifically, how do I find the `post` ID and the `post.wall` ID accordingly for `post_engagement` and `link_click` action types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to figure it out on my own. When creating a new ad, in a conversion typed campaign, an ad data object that includes tracking specs should be provided. These tracking specs should include some reference to a Facebook pixel.

```
"tracking_specs": [
    {
        "action.type": ["offsite_conversion"],
        "fb_pixel": [<pixel ID>]
    }, 
]
```

The pixels data can be obtained manually via the Facebook Business Manager or via the Facebook Marketing APIs:

```
GET /v2.10/{ad-account-id}/adspixels HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com
```

Read more in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/adspixels/

Regarding the `post` and `post.wall` IDs - these are automatically added by Facebook  when the ad is created. So there is no need to include theses when creating the ad.

Comment: "Regarding the post and post.wall IDs - these are automatically added by Facebook when the ad is created. So there is no need to include theses when creating the ad."

I have been going crazy for this, thank you so much man!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone searching for an answer in 2023. asaf's answer is totally correct **BUT** you also need to wait until Meta Business Manager processes your campaign in order to see `tracking_specs` into the API and in the Business Manager itself.